# A term for the extreme strength and skill of "stationary muscle control"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology

Is there a single term (preferred) or two-word phrase (acceptable), possibly technical, though not necessarily so, that conveys the idea of a person having extreme strength and skill at stationary muscle control?

By this, I mean able to remain still in a stationary, possibly rather awkward, position for extended periods of time. Think of [extreme yoga positions](https://www.google.com/search?q=extreme%20yoga%20positions&biw=1525&bih=682&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=KbqIVdWzOcL9yQSN3oGIAw&ved=0CCgQ7Ak&dpr=0.9) held for some extended length of time (granted, some of those one could not hold for too long; I'm thinking an hour or more, like [this abdominal plank record](http://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/world-records/longest-time-in-an-abdominal-plank-position/)).

Comment: If there isn't a single word for "stationary muscle control" then it's unlikely that there will be a single word for skill at it.

Comment: @DJClayworth: Actually, this is more about finding a term for "stationary muscle control" itself (to me, having such control is itself showing an extreme strength/skill with one's muscles to remain in that fixed state for an extended period). I'm just not familiar enough with the discipline of yoga or other such activities to know if there is a term for this or not.

Comment: @DJClayworth: Just edited the question to convey that I see the skill of "stationary muscle control" as being a show of "extreme strength and skill," as I could see how I originally worded it could be misconstrued as to what I was seeking.

Comment: This is probably at least in part related to what Ayurveda and yoga call the ***kapha*** body type (_kapha doṣa_ is one of the three [_doṣas_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dosha), or humours, in Ayurvedic medicine), though there are many aspects of _kapha_ that don’t necessarily relate to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for a word to describe skill at *isometric* exercise.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometric_exercise):

> Isometric exercise or isometrics are a type of strength training in
>   which the joint angle and muscle length do not change during
>   contraction (compared to concentric or eccentric contractions, called
>   dynamic/isotonic movements). Isometrics are done in static positions,
>   rather than being dynamic through a range of motion.

I would suggest **endurance** or **stamina** or **control** though I don't think either would work without a modifier.  e.g.

> Her extraordinary control is demonstrated by the perfection of her plank position and the length of time she is able to maintain it.

Comment: So: "isometric strength'?

Comment: @Avon: I suppose one might say that. It conveys part of what the OP wants. It may be that the question boils down to "What is an adjective for combined strength and control?". Then he can just modify that with "isometric" and have done.

Comment: Seems like [_extreme isometrics_](http://ntinfinity.weebly.com/extreme-isometrics.html), or [_long duration isometrics_](http://www.nicros.com/training/articles/training-with-long-duration-isometrics/) may be the most widely known term(s) for what I am referring to.

Answer (score 0):

**Tenacity**

*adj*: tenacious

> the quality or fact of being able to grip something firmly; grip.

**Brawny**

> physically strong; muscular.

**Endurance**/**stoicism**

> the ability to endure an unpleasant or difficult process or situation without giving way.

Source: Oxford Dictionaries

Comment: None of these convey the idea to me--yes, the feats I linked to show some tenacious people with much endurance (not really brawny, though, which is more the idea of a weight lifter). But none of these convey the meaning of "stationary muscle control" of themselves (nor even well if combined together; they do not improve upon my original phrase).

Comment: I think endurance does (the others don't in my mind) and is the only word I can think of that does. +1 for endurance

Comment: @Avon: _Endurance_, to me, is not specific enough. A marathon runner has endurance, so does a person caring for a loved-one in a coma, or person enduring the rigors of finishing medical school. The word has no inherent idea of _muscle_ nor _stationary_, but only (to some extent) _control_.